# Find a string in a file and copy the row

Tags: csv, vbscript

I am working with a CSV file and I want to check if there is a specific string in it. If so I want to copy the row where the string was found.

The code:

```
x = InputBox("String to find")

fileName = "file.csv"

Set oshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set fich = fs.OpenTextFile(fileName, 1, "True")

linea = fich.ReadAll

'here I want to read the row where I found the value of x

line = Left (linea, 117)
MsgBox line

fich.Close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read it line by line.

```
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
    Text = Inp.readline
    If InStr(LCase(Text), "cat") then Msgbox Text
Loop
```

To use in a command prompt

```
cscript //nologo C:\folder\file.vbs < C:\folder\FileToSearch.txt
```